# Map array of objects with matching records in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have array of objects inside which I have items and attachments as separated.

**Current Behaviour:**

```js
const data = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'Test',
   attachments: [
   {id: 1, itemId: -1, attachmentName: 'hello.jpg'},
   {id: 2, itemId: -1, attachmentName: 'world.jpg'},
   {id: 3, itemId: 2, attachmentName: 'image.jpg'}
   ],
   items: [
    {id: -1, itemName: 'Item One'},
    {id: 2, itemName: 'Item Two'},
   ]
}

console.log('data ', data);
```

Here to map attachments **with** items, we have `itemId` inside each attachment which will map with `id` of each item.

**Expected Result:**

```
 const data = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'Test',
   items: [
    { 
      id: -1, 
      itemName: 'Item One',  
      attachments: [
       {id: 1, itemId: -1, attachmentName: 'hello.jpg'},
       {id: 2, itemId: -1, attachmentName: 'world.jpg'}
     ]
    },
    {
     id: 2, 
     itemName: 'Item Two', 
     attachements: [
      {id: 3, itemId: 2, attachmentName: 'image.jpg'}
     ]
   },
  ]
}
```

Things I have tried,

```
const results = data.attachments.reduce((results, item) => {
    (results[item.id] = results[item.id] || []).push(item);
    return results;
}, {});
```

Tried grouping each attachment based on Id, but this doesn't come along way.

Could someone kindly help to achieve the desired output?

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a Map keyed by itemId, with the item objects as corresponding values, where each object gets an `attachments` array that is initially empty.

Then iterate the data to populate those attachment arrays.

Finally get the objects from the Map to construct the final object:

```js
const data = {id: 1,name: 'Test',attachments: [{id: 1, itemId: -1, attachmentName: 'hello.jpg'},{id: 2, itemId: -1, attachmentName: 'world.jpg'},{id: 3, itemId: 2, attachmentName: 'image.jpg'}],items: [{id: -1, itemName: 'Item One'},{id: 2, itemName: 'Item One'},]}

const {items, attachments, ...rest} = data;
const map = new Map(items.map(item => [item.id, {...item, attachments: []}]));
for (const attachment of attachments) {
    map.get(attachment.itemId).attachments.push(attachment);
}
const result = {...rest, items: [...map.values()]};

console.log(result);
```